# Get all distinct values from column1 in case of 2 similar rows, get the one with column2 not null

Tags: mysql, sql, dremio

I have a large table as dataset. If there are 2 similar rows with same date and id then how do I get the row for which another column `value` is not null?

```
SELECT *, row_number() 
   over (partition by id order by date desc) rowNumber 
FROM table where rowNumber = 1;
```

Comment: Why did you think row number a solution to this , I would have thought a not null test on ciol2 would suffice. Sample data and expected outcome as text would help clarify.

Comment: Hi, there are multiple rows initially for a single id, get the latest dated row for a particular id because eventually I need one row with latest timestamp. But incase there are duplicate after that filter for same time value then get the row for which col2 is non null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ordering by the column which has 2 values(1 row with null and 1 without null) helped

default ordering is ascending and NULLS LAST is the default for ascending order
and rowNumer=1 would give the row without null

Answer (score 0):

Please try this query:

```
select * from table where (id, date) in 
(select id, date from table group by id, table having count(1) > 1) 
and value is not null;
```